# How to collect and return instances with one method, having one generic type argument?

Tags: java, generics

My application is representing a Company, which has projects (`Project` class), and `Employees`. Every `Employee` is a `Worker`, every `Leader` is a `Worker`, and every `ProjectLeader` and `DeveloperLeader` is a `Leader` itself.

I want to create a method in the `Company` class, which accepts a type argument, and returns a `Set` containing all instances of the given type. The company has a projects set, representing all the projects:

```
private static Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

And every project has a List, representing all workers on the project:

```
public List<Worker> workersOnProject = new ArrayList<>();
```

So I want my method to be able to accept the following type arguments: `Project`, `Employee`, `Worker`, `Leader`, `ProjectLeader`, `DeveloperLeader`. My method is:

```
public <T> Set<T> getSameTypeEntity(Class<T> cls) {
        Set<T> sameTypeEntities = new HashSet<>();
        if (cls == com.example.project.Project.class) {
            sameTypeEntities.addAll((Collection<? extends T>) projects);
        } else {
            for (Project p : projects) {
                for (Object e : p.workersOnProject) {
                    if (e.getClass() == cls) {
                        sameTypeEntities.add((T) e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return sameTypeEntities;
    }
```

If I create for example a projectLeader instance, I use:

```
ProjectLeader pL1 = new ProjectLeader();
```

But when I call the method, like this:

```
getSameTypeEntity(Leader.class);
getSameTypeEntity(DeveloperLeader.class);
```

for the `Leader.class` argument my method returns an empty `Set`, but it works for `DeveloperLeader.class`. So I can not call it with superclass arguments (`Employee`, `Leader`) and for `Worker.class` it only gives back instances that were created like this (`Worker w1 = new Worker();`), but it should also give back all the Leader subtypes, because they are also `Worker`s.

How can I return every subclass instance, when calling with "higher level" arguments? I'm not even sure, I'm using generics in a proper way, so any clean code or usage advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the semantics you desire, this small change may be what you want.

Replace this:

```
if (e.getClass() == cls) {
```

with this:

```
if(cls.isInstance(e))
```

The difference is that this checks not only for an exact match, but also allows subclasses or classes that implement the specified interface.

---

And while we're at it: here's your method, re-written in a more idiomatic Java 8 style

```
public <T> Set<T> getSameTypeEntity(Class<T> cls) {
    Set<T> sameTypeEntities = new HashSet<>();
    if (cls == Project.class) {
        sameTypeEntities.addAll((Collection<? extends T>) projects);
    } else {
        projects.stream()
                .flatMap(p -> p.getWorkersOnProject().stream())
                .filter(cls::isInstance)
                .map(cls::cast)
                .forEach(sameTypeEntities::add);
    }
    return sameTypeEntities;
}
```